# File headers are not being found in Xcode project

Tags: xcode, parsing, cocoapods

i just bought the newest imac. 
running OS 10.9.5- 64 bit
I am using cocoapods version 0.34.1
xcode latest stable build (6.01)

And for some reason the repo ive been working on for a year now is having all kinds of trouble finding pod header files.

for parse, im getting 'Parse/Parse.h' file not found,
I could be wrong but i dont think its specific to parse.

Nothing is different about my project environment except for the new computer.

Comment: What do you get when you run `pod install`?

Comment: Also, are you sure you’re opening the `.xcworkspace` file, not the `.xcodeproj` file?

Comment: Of course. The issue was actually with the test target. I deleted the test target and the problem went away

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `pod 'Parse-IOS'` change it to `pod 'Parse', '~> 1.4'` because has been deprecated.

Also, does it happen for pods to not been found by ProjectTests?
If so, add at the top of the podfile this line:

```
link_with  ['ProjectName', 'ProjectNameTests']
```

and at your project Build Setting->Other Linker Flags, add $(inherited).

Comment: Upvoting this because this may work. The issue is with projecttests. I just deleted projecttest but if you need it this may work.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the test target, remove it from the build to solve this.
Go to edit scheme under project and expand all the items in the left column. Highlight any references to test and hit the minus button.

This information can save you from banging your head into the wall.